# Traces in Solana

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, data, historical-data

I'm looking to create a data pipeline that gets traces (both value transfers and contract executions like on the EVM) but, I can't find the equivalent to it on Solana's VM.

*What is the equivalent to [EVM traces](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/what-are-evm-traces) in Solana's VM?*

Appreciate any help in this direction.

Cheers!

**Update:**

- The smallest unit of execution is an [Instruction](https://docs.solana.com/terminology#instruction) and is within a Transaction.
- The Transaction object has metadata called [InnerInstruction](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#inner-instructions-structure) which has a set of instructions within a transaction.
- However, I believe this can be [disabled during a transaction](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction) (so not transparent)

So while I made some progress, *I'm still in a quandary on how to get all lowest-level traces of transactions when Inner Instructions can be disabled*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with EVM traces but it seems very similar to emitting events in Solana.

We use events to log messages (anything you would do with `msg!()`).  But they are not human readable as they are base64 encoded. Also `msg!()` with string formatting is relatively expensive for compute units

Here is an example

```
pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        emit!(MyEvent {
            data: 5,
            label: "hello".to_string(),
        });
        Ok(())
    }

#[event]
pub struct MyEvent {
    pub data: u64,
    #[index]
    pub label: String,
}
```

And in the client side, you listen for events

```
listener = program.addEventListener("MyEvent", (event, slot) => {
    console.log([event, slot]);

    //      [ { data: 5,
    //        label: "hello".to_string(), } ,
    //       123131313 ]

});
```

Comment: thanks for getting back so quickly! That's very interesting. Actually in EVM, the solidity smart contract language has Emit/Events as well which looks similar to what you've shown. 

From what I understand about EVM traces, they exist at an abstraction level below solidity, closer to the byte code layer. Its meant to grap any type of transaction (b/w accounts, contracts and account-contracts) on the entire blockchain. So wondering if Solana has something like that. And the Inner Instruction looked like it.

Comment: The mapping of the EVM Emit/Events is to `msg!` at Solana. Anchor framework provides the `emit!` macro with functionality but still based on top fo the `msg!` call. I think there is no more functionality above that. You can check discussion around the topic of events at Solana issues https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/14076

Comment: + it sounds strange to me that the `inner instructions` could be somehow disabled. But I acknowledge that I don't know what exactly the documentation means with the phrase `null if inner instruction recording was not enabled during this transaction`. To me the inner transaction is recorded when they are called (a CPI call happens). When there is no CPI call then no inner transaction can be recorded. Strange that there could be some special switch for recording or not recording.